# How to require alt text when uploading an image in the experience editor?

Tags: experience-editor, media-library

[image]

How can I make this field required so that a user can't upload an image without the alternate text box having a value?

Comment: I wondered this same thing and came across this article - https://mskutta.github.io/2019/11/18/sitecore-how-to-enforce-required-alt-text-on-image-items/
I hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **Field Validation Rules**.

Out of the box, Sitecore has a validation rule called **Alt Required**. Which you can find in the content editor here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/System/Alt Required`

If you want the validation rule to stop people from being able to save the new image item, then you need to change this rule to fire a **Fatal Error** rather than just a Warning.

You can do this by updating the Parameters field to this value:

`Text=The Alt field is empty.&Result=FatalError`

With that in place, you need to access the **Alt field** from the Image Base template: `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Image/Image/Alt`

Here you find the rule has already been added to **Validator Bar**. You should add it to the to the other fields (Quick Action Bar & Validate Button) as well as this will allow people to find out what is invalidating the item. Also workflow if you are using them at all.

[image: Alt validation rules]

Now when a user tries to upload an image and forgets to add an Alt Tag, they will get the following alert blocking them from saving the item.

[image: Alt Tag warning]

They can find out what is invalidating the item, by Navigating to `REVIEW => Validation`

The dialog window will show that the **Has required alt text** is causing a fatal error, blocking the save process.

[image: Alt field validation dialog window]

Comment: Thanks! But this does it on save which I've already done. My issue is making sure that before you're allowed to upload a file you must have set alt text (which is a field you can set in the experience editor before a file is uploaded) see screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `Set Default Alternate Text on Images Uploaded` to the Sitecore Media Library, of course, it is not a sort of validation but it would be a good alternative rather than blocking the content author each time for alt text.

`<getMediaCreatorOptions>` pipeline processor to set default alternate text on an image Item during upload:

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMediaCreatorOptions;
 
namespace Sitecore.Sandbox.Pipelines.GetMediaCreatorOptions
{
    public class SetDefaultAlternateTextIfNeed
    {
        public void Process(GetMediaCreatorOptionsArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Options.AlternateText))
            {
                return;
            }
 
            args.Options.AlternateText = GetAlternateText(args);
        }
 
        protected virtual string GetAlternateText(GetMediaCreatorOptionsArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Options.Destination) || args.Options.Destination.IndexOf("/") < 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
 
            int startofNameIndex = args.Options.Destination.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
            return args.Options.Destination.Substring(startofNameIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getMediaCreatorOptions>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Sandbox.Pipelines.GetMediaCreatorOptions.SetDefaultAlternateTextIfNeed, Sitecore.Sandbox"/>
      </getMediaCreatorOptions>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Reference and Credit: [Set Default Alternate Text on Images Uploaded](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/06/18/set-default-alternate-text-on-images-uploaded-to-the-sitecore-media-library/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below mentioned steps and try:

1.Set up validation rules for the Alt field on Image items.

2.Configure the validation rule to show a "Fatal Error" if alt text is empty.

3.Prevent saving Image items with empty alt text by setting the validation result to "Fatal Error".

4.Create a custom workflow with a Validation Action to catch validation errors during the Publish Command.

5.Configure the workflow to subject the alt text field to validation.

Reference Link - https://mskutta.github.io/2019/11/18/sitecore-how-to-enforce-required-alt-text-on-image-items/